# Ruby 1.9.3 / Passenger 3.0.9 upgrade causing upstream prematurely closed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I upgraded to ruby 1.9.3 this morning, kept the same version of Rails 3.0.8 and installed / updated passenger-3.0.9. Everything seems to run OK when I launch the application, until I try and login (make a database connection), I get a 502 Bad Gateway and the following error message in the console:

> [NOTE] You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or
>   extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome. For details:
>   http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
>
> 2011/10/31 08:37:22 [error] 6201#0: *6 upstream prematurely closed
>   connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:unix:/passenger_helper_server:", host: "0.0.0.0:3000"

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed in the last week on the [Passenger mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/d1bc0b413fe1c2b3?pli=1).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's still an open bug:

http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=714

Only solution I know of is to downgrade to 1.9.2-p290 until it's fixed.